# Im getting latitude and longitude out of date

Tags: android, gps, location

I using the new API for get location: android.https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Some times when I get the location, It come out of date. I get out at some place and go to another place, then the application returns the first place location to me. It happens when I out the WiFi. When I use the WiFi it works perfectly. Am I missing some method or something else?

```
public class NewGPSTracker implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


private LocationRequest lr;
private LocationClient lc;
Location location;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
Context context;
static Boolean status = false;  
public int res = 0;
boolean conectado;

public  NewGPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    lr = LocationRequest.create();
    lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    lr.setInterval(5000);       
    lr.setFastestInterval(1000);
    lc = new LocationClient(context, this, this);       
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  

    if (conectado) {
        lc.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);
        location = lc.getLastLocation();
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {     
    Log.e("NewGPSTracker", ""+arg0);

}       

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    conectado = true;
    Log.i("NewGPSTracker", "Google Play Services Conectado.");
    lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);    

    location = lc.getLastLocation();

    if(location != null){
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    }
}   

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}   


public void connect(){
    lc.connect();
}

public void disconnect(){
    lc.disconnect();
}   


@Override
public void onDisconnected() {

}


public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I exactly don't know what are you using. But when i use google API for this situation, solved a issue like that.

Now line that at top always uses **HIGH_ACCURACY** of GPS/WI-FI. And your situation it looks like WI-FI always.. As you know there are two method to find user's location. (GPS/WI-FI) when you change your GPS location and not opening your **WI-FI** it should keep showing first.

So try to change it as a static variable like GPS, if it's possible.

Sorry for my bad english, complicated situation..

Comment: i just said it. Check this class, LocationRequest if there is GPS exists

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference of the time stamp of the location to the current time.
If it is more  than some seconds, it is an old positoin, e.g the last known.
In that case wait for the next position, untill time difference is less than some seconds.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that?

Comment: Something deltaTimeMillis = Math.abs(currentTime - location.getTime()); if (deltaTimeMillis > 10 * 1000) { ignore location }

Comment: @SercanOzdemir This is the only way.